# Importing Child Classes Dynamically in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, dynamic

I have an Employee abstract class that declares a getPhrase() method.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Employee(ABC):

    def __init__(self, phrase):
        self.phrase = phrase
        return

    @abstractmethod
    def getPhrase(self):
        pass
```

The implementations of this class are stored in separate files.

```
from Employee import Employee

class Doctor(Employee):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("I love health!")
        return

    def getPhrase(self):
        return self.phrase
```

The main application is an infinite loop that asks for the file paths to the Employee child class files. It should make an instance of the class and add it to an array of Employee's.

```
import importlib
import Employee

emp_list = []

while (True):

    # to be replaced by a file picker
    input_value = input("Enter file path or e to exit... ")
    if (input_value == "e"):
        break

    module = importlib.import_module(input_value, ".")

    # find Employee derived class inside the module
    # make an instance of the class

    emp = 0 # what do I put here?

    # add the instance to an array
    emp_list.append(emp)

    # print all of the phrases
    for e in emp_list:
        print(e.getPhrase())
```

How do I use the import_module() method correctly?
Heres the file structure:

```
project folder
|
+ - main.py
  - Employee.py
  - EmpFolder
    |
    + - Doctor.py
      - Teacher.py
```

Comment: "The main application is an infinite loop that asks for the file paths to the Employee child class files" But why? What is the purpose of that? Normally you would just include all the types you need explicitly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It has to do with the nature of the application. It will essentially be a server doing calculations with these 'Employee' classes running all day every day. But I need to be able to continuously update them and add more.

Comment: you want a plugin architecture, I imagine. take a look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCE1bDoit9Q but there's a lot you can search for.